# How to get the mean of a column in many csv folder in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, dataframe

I have a csv folder with many files. Each csv file looks like this

csv 1

```
   Name   Sales
 0 Sam    250
 0 Steve  554
 0 Ann    244
```

csv 2

```
   Name   Sales
 0 Sam    250
 0 Steve  554
 0 Ann    244
```

Is there a way to get the total sale average for each csv

Looking to have this

```
   sale mean 
0  349.333333
1  349.333333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `csv` files have a comma as `seperator`, the following code should work in a generalized way:

```
import os

folder = r'home\desktop\path_to_csvfiles'

means = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder, file))
    means.append(df['Sales'].mean())

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'sale_mean':means})
```

Comment: got an error "Initializing from file failed" but fixed by slightly changing it to pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder, file), engine='python')

Answer (score 1):

Read your file in pandas, use the `.mean()` function to add a mean column, and save the file back to CSV:

```
import pandas as pd

# read your file
df = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv", sep="\t", header=1)
df["sale_mean"] = df.sale.mean()

# write it back
df.to_csv("csv1_altered.csv", header=true, index=False)
```

Hope it helps.